# Why a condition make an operator to be of finite rank?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, proof-explanation

The question is given in the following picture:

[image]

A part of the answer to letter(b) is given in the following picture:

[image]

But I did not understand the first line in the answer,why $K$ in this case is of finite rank? and why it is specially of rank 0? could anyone clarify it for me please?

Comment: Do you know anything else about $\phi$ and $\psi$? Assuming that are in $L_2[a,b]$ (or representatives of classes of such), already the expression $\phi \circ \psi = 0 _v$ is troublesome, because the image of $\psi$ does not necessarily have to be contained in $[a,b]$ again. And even if this was the case, the example $\psi \equiv 1$, $\phi(x)=1-x$ would provide a counterexample on $[0,1]$.

Comment: They are arbitrary systems of functions in $L_{2}([a,b])$ @jabo